# String content from dialog popup feeding into EditText field

Tags: android

I am trying to create a feature whereby the user enters in a name in a dialog popup box, then the name entered is automatically fed through into an EditText field on the next page, kinda like requesting a title name, then making that the title of the next page. The dialog popup part is working, but I am having issues getting the value stored in the 'm_Text' string variable into the EditText field. Please can someone help me out!!!

Here is the code for the page on which the dialog box is called....

```
    package com.evicapture.loadsave;

//import com.example.camerademo.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class IntroMenu extends Activity {

    public static String m_Text = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewCase);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(IntroMenu.this);
                builder.setTitle("Insert Case Name/No:");

                final EditText input = new EditText(IntroMenu.this);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
                builder.setView(input);

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.evicapture.loadsave.CASEINFO");
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });

                builder.show();

            }
        });


    }
```

and the code for the field it goes through to with the EditText field....

```
    package com.evicapture.loadsave;

//import com.example.camerademo.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class caseInfo extends Activity {
    EditText etCaseNameNo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.case_info_form);
        etCaseNameNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvCaseNameNo);

        etCaseNameNo.setText(IntroMenu.m_Text);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Back1);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),IntroMenu.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

If anything else is required, please ask.. I am new to android programming, and am struggling, so please be kind..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass m_text(String) through intent.

For that you can use:

[putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D%29): Add extended data to the intent.

```
final String MESSAGE = "com.evicapture.loadsave.username";

m_Text = input.getText().toString();
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.evicapture.loadsave.CASEINFO");
myIntent.putExtra(MESSAGE, strName);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

For retreive you can use:

```
  extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString(MESSAGE);
    }
etCaseNameNo.setText(newString);
```